# Change attribute table name in Tiger file

Tags: qgis, tiger

I'm fairly new at QGIS, though pretty experienced with ArcMap. So I thought I would learn it with a fun data set, a Census bureau tiger file. Specifically the Public Use Microdata Area (PUMA) which can be found at.

https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html

Each of the attributes has a alphanumeric name which corresponds to the metadata with the actual descriptions. When I try to open the metadata QGIS slows down until it's unusable. How can I transfer or best leverage the metadata to know what the attributes are. I know it's a broad and somewhat simple question, but I really cannot find a good way to do this.

Comment: And it would seem if I join the main polygon to any table it crashes upon trying to read the attribute table.